# Can we implement a "Your Open Questions" section on the sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, unanswered-questions

When a user is logged in, can we implement a sidebar widget displaying his/her Open Questions for quick browsing or attention?

```
+-------------------------------------+
| YOUR OPEN QUESTIONS                 |
|   Questions those are not answered  |
|   or any of the answer is accepted  |
|   by you.                           |
|                                     |
| * The Question #3 [x]               |
| * The elaborated and detailed       |
|   question #14 [x]                  |
| * Question #32 [x]                  |
|                                     |
|                  All My Questions » |
+-------------------------------------+
```

The criteria of choosing such question automatically can be either:

- A Question by the author, never answered
- A Question by the author, was answered, but none of the answer is marked *Accepted* by the author

The system can automatically remove any Question from the list, if:

- A Question asked by the author, was answered, and Is Accepted by the author.

Flexibility by the user:

- Author/User can remove any of the listed question from the widget with a simple click into the cross `[x]` button beside each of the question.

#### I know, the question is ***WHY?***

Answer may be:

- To provide a little bit of ease. Just a simple click to his/her newly questioned Question[s] at a glance.
- Importantly, to encourage the author to *Accept* any of the answer, if it satisfy him/her.
- To encourage the author to grab attention for his/her unanswered question[s] by announcing that to Bounty.

Let's the community decide?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for [SO meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), since I suppose it would have to be implemented globally. That being said, this has my upvote as well. I think it's a great idea that the entire SE.network could actually benefit from!

Comment: @JohannesPille standing recommendation is to raise issues on local meta first, even if they apply globally. Of course "local" depends on point of view somewhat. :)

Comment: Aight, fair enuff, @Rarst. Did not mean to overly critique this. Given that we're on this: Standing recommendation is for mods not to migrate globally applicable questions or also for users to ask them locally? I.e. if a user, that is active on SO and SO.meta as well, had such an idea - should he or she raise it there or in his/her most active stack's meta? Just curious.

Comment: @JohannesPille mods do not touch it usually, it's presumed to be in higher powers hands. If user is active on SO meta I would assume just asking there would go smooth enough.

Comment: I'm not active in SO Meta till now. For now, if thing's in our hand, we can activate it in our territory. Then SO will clone it into global. Pardon me if I'm wrong with this thought.

Comment: You are likely wrong in the assumption that "we can activate it in our territory". SO staff would have to notice it and deem it worthy of consideration - regardless of whether here, there or elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I got it now. Actually, We, as a Bangla Wikipedian, can control many things locally then MetaWiki. It's Ok. We hope for the best for our community here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [rejected the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199644/1438) on Meta Stack Exchange.  I suggested a search that will give you the information you are looking for:

```
user:me hasaccepted:no
```

When I did the [search for your user id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a22728%20hasaccepted%3ano), I noticed you have 22 such results and only three have even one upvote.  Only 8 have [1 or more](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22728+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1) answers.  So I can see why you are interested in the feature.

You might want to take a few moments to go through your old, unanswered questions and see if they are still relevant.  Perhaps you've solved the problem or found a work-around.  If so, write up your solution as a self-answer.  Otherwise, it might be helpful to follow the advice given in "[What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)".

Comment: That's not really a proper answer, Jon. I got 11 results (close to 10%), which are currently not solvable - hence no solution. But I'd appreciate to see that, so less questions stay open as lots of new users simply forget about their old questions. We have to remind them too often that they should _actually care_ about what they've asked - therefore my comment on the question and my upvote for that feature request.

Comment: @kaiser: questions that are honestly not solvable probably ought to be closed.  You can get a view of all [unanswered questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered) on the site as well as unanswered in a particlar tag.  (For instance [permalinks](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/permalinks).)  Occationaly old unanswered questions get [bumped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36824/1438) to the mainpage as well.

Comment: Not really close-worthy. Often they serve as blueprint or research base for trac tickets that are moved into upcoming versions. Anyway, it's about users who don't care or simply forget about their open questions and the feature request might help solving that issue.